# Ubuntu says Unable to Locate Package (no not the common issue)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I tried to install some third party packages by following instructions on this URL.

After doing the following, I started to get the error "Unable to locate the package"

```
root@ubuntu:/# cd /root/
root@ubuntu:~# wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
root@ubuntu:~# apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
```

After googling I found if I deleted the sources.list file it will be recreated, which I did. But whenever I try to install anything it gives the error "Unable to locate package". I tried generating the source.list file and pasting the content it seems to work but, when I go the following.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it gives me this error.

```
W: GPG error: http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/grizzly Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5EDB1B62EC4926EA
```

How can I solve this, I have been googling for days now, can't just re-install my server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to reinstall your server because of this.
This is just a problem with handling the keys that sign the repositories' contents.
You need to read the `apt-key(8)` and `gpg` manpages.

Try this procedure:

- look for the public key hinted in the error message.

  ```
  # gpg --recv-keys 5EDB1B62EC4926EA
  gpg: requesting key EC4926EA from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
  gpg: key EC4926EA: public key "Canonical Cloud Archive Signing Key <ftpmaster@canonical.com>" imported
  gpg: Total number processed: 1
  gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
  ```
- once the key has been downloaded, export it to a file.

  ```
  # gpg --export EC4926EA > canonical.asc
  ```
- now you can add it to the APT keyring.

  ```
  # apt-key add canonical.asc
  ```
- update the indices by issuing:

  ```
  # aptitude update
  ```
- now there should be no problem listing packages from that repository, provided you have it properly configured in your `sources.list`.

  ```
  # aptitude search $package
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I get this result.

gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/himsadmin/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error

Comment: That error message means exactly that: review the ownership and permissions of your `gpg.conf`, it should belong to you, your group and don't be group or others readable or writable.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works perfectly now. Your answers were specific, clear and timely.